# How do I replicate this regex in JavaScript without lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Here's my Regex in C#:

```
(?<!\([\w\s]+)\bSWORD\b
```

I now need this in JavaScript. I'm a newbie to regex, so I have no idea how I would do this without the lookbehind. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us examples of what would and wouldn't match? What purpose the regexp serves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have a lookahead as well, there is a neat trick. Reverse the input string and apply the reversed regular expression:

```
\bDROWS\b(?![\w\s]+\()
```

If you want the position of the match in the actual input string, then you can find it as:

```
lengthOfInputString - (foundMatchPosition + lengthOfMatch)
```

Comment: IIRC this could cause issues with some character encodings, so don't use this when internationalization support is needed.

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with converting to JS, but I'm having a problem. This new one is now only matching on WORDS once.

Comment: @edsaltz make sure to use the `g` modifier (`/\bDROWS\b(?![\w\s]+\()/g`)

Comment: @zzzzBov I guess it depends on whether the reversing is done correctly. And I don't think JavaScript regexes handle unicode correctly anyway.